# Anchor Links doesn’t work at my navigation, when I add JavaScript logic

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a navigation bar that shows the menu categories. I want the category jump labels to get an other bootstrap class when the corresponding heading is visible in the viewport. All these functions work as they should. Unfortunately the anchor links don't work anymore when I add the event listener for the scroll in the navigation bar navbar2 (second Event Listener) It works exactly as it should on the Safari, even with the second event listener, but not on other browsers.

UPDATE: I found this error message while debugging. With and without clicking the Anchor Link: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '' is not a valid selector.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
<!-- Bootstrap implementation and other things-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meine Speisekarten</title>
    <link href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
       
        .badge {
            margin-right: 5px !important;
        }
       .secondnavbar{
        width:100%;
        height: 55px;
        background-color: white;      
        font-size: 120%;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
       }
       .secondnavbar .item{
        margin-left: 10px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: auto;
        float:left;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
       }
       .außen{
       margin-left:10px;
       }
   
       .scroll-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  
    scrollbar-width: none;  
}
 
.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
 
    </style>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 style="text-align:left;text-transform:uppercase;margin-top:20px;">Meine Speisekarte<br></h2>
                <p style="color:#61676f;text-align:left;font-size:120%; margin-bottom: 35px;">Ansicht deiner gesamten
                    Speisekarte.</p>
                <hr style="background-color:black;margin-top:40px;">
                <br>
                <p style="font-size:130%;"><strong>Restaurant: <?php echo $restaurant_name;?></strong></p></div></div></div><br>
<div class="secondnavbar">
    <div class="außen">
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT mcv.id, mcv.name FROM menu_category mc JOIN menu_category_values mcv ON mc.category_id = mcv.id WHERE mc.restaurant_id = ? ORDER BY category_id ASC";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $restaurant_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $categories_result = $stmt->get_result();
 
            while ($category_row = $categories_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $category_id = $category_row['id'];
                $category_name = $category_row['name'];
 
                echo '<div class="item">';
                echo '<a href="#' . $category_name . '">';
                echo '<span style="font-size: 16px; padding: 10px;" class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-light">' . $category_name . '</span>';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT mcv.id, mcv.name, mcv.img_link, mc.id AS menu_category_id
                        FROM menu_category mc
                        JOIN menu_category_values mcv ON mc.category_id = mcv.id
                        WHERE mc.restaurant_id = ? ORDER BY category_id asc";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $restaurant_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $categories_result = $stmt->get_result();
 
                while ($category_row = $categories_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<h3 id="' . $category_row['name'] . '" style="margin-top:2em;">' . $category_row['name'] . '</h3>';
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<style>';
                    echo '@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {';
                    echo '    #desktop { display: none; }';
                    echo '}';
                    echo '@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {';
                    echo '    #mobile { display: none; }';
                    echo '}';
                    echo '</style>';
                   
                    echo '<div id="desktop" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">';
                    echo '    <img src="' . $category_row['img_link'] . '" alt="' . $category_row['name'] . '" style="object-fit: none; object-position: 50% 110%; width: 100%; height: auto;">';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div id="mobile" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="' . $category_row['img_link'] . '" alt="' . $category_row['name'] . '" style="width: 100%; height: auto; object-position: 50% 110%;"></div>';
                    echo '<br>';
                   
 
                    $menu_category_id = $category_row['menu_category_id'];
 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM courts WHERE menu_category_id = ?";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $menu_category_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $dishes_result = $stmt->get_result();
 
                    while ($row = $dishes_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo '<div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">';
                            echo '    <div class="card-body">';
                            echo '        <h3 style="margin-bottom:20px;">' . $row['name'] . '</h3>';
                            ....
                        }
 
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // JavaScript, um die Navbar beim Scrollen zu fixieren
        const secondNavbar = document.querySelector('.secondnavbar');
        const initialOffset = secondNavbar.offsetTop; // Y-Offset der Navbar
 
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= initialOffset) {
                secondNavbar.classList.add('fixed-top');
            } else {
                secondNavbar.classList.remove('fixed-top');
            }
        });
 

        const badgeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.secondnavbar .außen .item');
 
   badgeItems.forEach(item => {
    const badge = item.querySelector('.badge');
   
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        badge.classList.remove('text-bg-light');
        badge.classList.add('badge-dark');
    });
 
    item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        badge.classList.remove('badge-dark');
        badge.classList.add('text-bg-light');
    });
});



// JavaScript, um die Navbar-Badges basierend auf dem gescrollten Abschnitt zu ändern
const sectionHeadings = document.querySelectorAll('h3[id]'); // Alle h3-Überschriften mit 'id' attribut
 
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    // Überprüfe jede Überschrift und aktualisiere die Badges entsprechend
    let found = false;
    for (let i = sectionHeadings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const heading = sectionHeadings[i];
        const sectionId = heading.getAttribute('id');
        const badgeItem = document.querySelector(`.secondnavbar .außen .item a[href="#${sectionId}"] .badge`);
 
        if (badgeItem) {
            const sectionTop = heading.offsetTop - 100; // Etwas Offset für bessere Anpassung
 
            if (!found && scrollTop >= sectionTop) {
                badgeItem.classList.remove('text-bg-light');
                badgeItem.classList.add('badge-dark');
                found = true;
            } else {
                badgeItem.classList.remove('badge-dark');
                badgeItem.classList.add('text-bg-light');
            }
        }
    }
});
 

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
 
    // Überprüfe jede Überschrift und aktualisiere die Badges entsprechend
    let found = false;
    for (let i = sectionHeadings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const heading = sectionHeadings[i];
        const rect = heading.getBoundingClientRect();
 
        if (rect.top < window.innerHeight && !found) {
            found = true;
           
            // Aktualisiere Navbar-Badges
            badgeItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
            badgeItems[i].classList.add('active');
           
            // Scrollen Sie die Navbar automatisch
            const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.scroll-container');
            const selectedItem = badgeItems[i];
            const offsetLeft = selectedItem.offsetLeft;
            const scrollPosition = offsetLeft - (window.innerWidth / 2) + (selectedItem.offsetWidth / 2);
           
            scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
        }
    }
});
 
    </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

I tried to change the second Event Listener and summarise the two Event Listener into one function. No console errors. I expect, when I have the right h3 with the fitting id in the viewport, the jump in the scrollbar to the fitting item and the change of the class of the bootstrap badge.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
const badgeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.secondnavbar .außen .item');
const sectionHeadings = document.querySelectorAll('h3[id]');

const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    let activeIndex = -1;

    // Determine the index of the active section heading
    for (let i = sectionHeadings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const heading = sectionHeadings[i];
        const rect = heading.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (rect.top < window.innerHeight) {
            activeIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Update Navbar-Badges
    badgeItems.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (index === activeIndex) {
            item.querySelector('.badge').classList.add('badge-dark');
            item.querySelector('.badge').classList.remove('text-bg-light');
        } else {
            item.querySelector('.badge').classList.remove('badge-dark');
            item.querySelector('.badge').classList.add('text-bg-light');
        }
    });

    // Scroll the Navbar automatically
    const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.scroll-container');
    if (activeIndex !== -1) {
        const selectedItem = badgeItems[activeIndex];
        const offsetLeft = selectedItem.offsetLeft;
        const scrollPosition = offsetLeft - (window.innerWidth / 2) + (selectedItem.offsetWidth / 2);
        scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
    }
};

badgeItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        item.querySelector('.badge').classList.remove('text-bg-light');
        item.querySelector('.badge').classList.add('badge-dark');
    });

    item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        item.querySelector('.badge').classList.remove('badge-dark');
        item.querySelector('.badge').classList.add('text-bg-light');
    });
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

By consolidating the scroll-related logic into a single event listener, we minimize the potential for conflicts and improve the overall readability of the code. This should help ensure that both the scroll behavior and the navigation click functionality work smoothly together, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. That's better. But it still doesn't change anything. It works on Safari but not at other browsers.